# What is the right site to ask about Foursquare app

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was wondering where to go and ask about Foursquare. My first thought, since foursquare is on web, was [WebApps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). But the question would be rather about the app I have installed on my Android phone (so [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)). But the app can be also installed on iPhone or other devices. So maybe even [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)?

I want to ask how does Foursquare's algorithm for sorting nearby places work. And I want to ask, to understand what to do, or where to be (or how to adjust my position) to get more suitable results.

Finally, I'm actually considering Android SE vs. WebApps SE.

Comment: What exactly do you want to ask?

Comment: Do you want to know the details of how the algorithm works so that you can write your own similar algorithm? If so, Stack Overflow would probably be a good place for your question.

Comment: You might want to formulate a better question from ["How do they do it?"...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131866/172936) Why not come up with your own algorithm and then post a question on Stack Overflow if you have problems implementing it.

Comment: Not Super User. From the [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://superuser.com/faq#questions) section questions about "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer" are explicitly off topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ask how does Foursquare's algorithm for sorting nearby places work. And I want to ask, to understand what to do, or where to be (or how to adjust my position) to get more suitable results.

Seems like something suited for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers
>   who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions
>   about software development. If you have a question about…
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts

---

- Webapps doesn't do web dev/algorithm questions.
- Android doesn't do development questions either.
- Super User doesn't do questions on algorithms, it's about use of *computer* software & hardware

Comment: Where is @ChrisF? Does he approve this message?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but the programmers.SE FAQ states that questions can be related to "algorithm and data structure **concepts**".  I don't really think that "what algorithm do *they* use" is acceptable there.  You'd have to come with an existing algorithm to ask questions about it... I'd love to hear what @chr has to say about it...

Comment: @TheEstablishment - I don't disapprove of this message :). The question (as stated) is a variant on "Send me the codez", so prove me wrong.

Comment: If the question is about the algorithm from a programming perspective, it will probably work on Programmers, but it will definitely not work if it's from the app user's perspective or a "show me the algorithm" type of question.